# Syntax error: missingl before statement while outputting MongoDB query to a text file

Tags: file, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am 1 day old to MongoDB so bear with me. I am simply trying to output a simple query to a *.json file. The query is:

`db.collection.findOne()` *// collection is substituted with the correct collection name, the query preludes 'use db' command where db is substituted with correct db name*

Then,  in reference to [this](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/directing-mongodb-query-results-to-a-file/) article and a bunch of other SO answers, I perform the following query:

```
--eval "printjson(db.results.findOne())" >> sample.json
```

I even created a blank sample.json file, and I experimented --eval with -eval etc. I keep getting:

**SyntaxError: missing ;before statement (shell):1**

I add semi colons at arbitrary places, but I have no idea why this doesn't work for me.

Can anybody point out what I am missing here?

Complete sequence of commands:

```
mongo
use dbname
--eval "printjson(db.collectionName.findOne())" >> sample.json
```

P.S: The command  db.collectionName.findOne() does give me an output

Comment: can you post the complete command starting with "mongo ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--eval should be passed as an argument to "mongo" command.  I tried below and it worked:

```
C:\>mongo localhost:27017/dbname --eval "printjson(db.results.findOne())" >> sample.json
```

Comment: wait, I am in the mongo command line shell. (unix environment), but I'll try the above

Comment: ha, that did it for me. I did not realize that I had to be outside of the mongo shell environment for the output to be added to a file. Is there noway I can do this while I am inside the mongo shell ?

Comment: I don't think it's do-able, but using [load()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/) you can run JS files from within the Mongo shell.  I would recommend you to post a separate question and someone from the community might suggest an approach.