# Printing Mongo query output to a file while in the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, io, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

2 days old with Mongo and I have a SQL background so bear with me. As with mysql, it is very convenient to be in the MySQL command line and output the results of a query to a file on the machine. I am trying to understand how I can do the same with Mongo, **while being in the shell**

I can easily get the output of a query I want by being outside of the shell and executing the following command:

```
mongo localhost:27017/dbname --eval "printjson(db.collectionName.findOne())" > sample.json
```

The above way is fine, but it requires me to exit the mongo shell or open a new terminal tab to execute this command. It would be very convenient if I could simply do this while still being inside the shell.

P.S: the Question is an offshoot of a question I posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540405/syntax-error-missingl-before-statement-while-outputting-mongodb-query-to-a-text/22541861#22541861)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no a interactive option for output to file, there is a previous SO question related with this: [Printing mongodb shell output to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/printing-mongodb-shell-output-to-file)

However, you can log all the shell session if you invoked the shell with tee command:

```
$ mongo | tee file.txt
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.2
connecting to: test
> printjson({this: 'is a test'})
{ "this" : "is a test" }
> printjson({this: 'is another test'})
{ "this" : "is another test" }
> exit
bye
```

Then you'll get a file with this content:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.2
connecting to: test
> printjson({this: 'is a test'})
{ "this" : "is a test" }
> printjson({this: 'is another test'})
{ "this" : "is another test" }
> exit
bye
```

To remove all the commands and keep only the json output, you can use a command similar to:

```
tail -n +3 file.txt | egrep -v "^>|^bye" > output.json
```

Then you'll get:

```
{ "this" : "is a test" }
{ "this" : "is another test" }
```

Comment: sigh, I wish this was possible, oh well, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Good answer, but using the cursor keys distorts the output in tmux, to the point where it's pretty much "paste a command, CTRL+C "

Comment: I wish there was workaround like this when using mongosh from within compass

Answer (score 60):

We can do it this way -

```
mongo db_name --quiet --eval 'DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 2000; db.users.find({}).limit(2000).toArray()' > users.json
```

The `shellBatchSize` argument is used to determine how many rows is the mongo client allowed to print. Its default value is 20.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not safe, other useless junk is captured too with some ssl setups:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23810

Comment: New versions of mongo shell deprecated shellbatchSize. The new syntax is: `mongo db_name --quiet --eval 'config.set("displayBatchSize", 2000); db.users.find({}).limit(2000).toArray()' > users.json`

Comment: If using a query operator that starts with `$` keep the single quotes in mind so that bash (or whatever shell you're using) doesn't try to interpret the operator as a variable. `mongo --eval 'db.coll.find().sort({$natural: -1})'` works but using a double quote wouldn't work here.

Answer (score 37):

If you invoke the shell with script-file, db address, and --quiet arguments, you can redirect the output (made with print() for example) to a file:

```
mongo localhost/mydatabase --quiet myScriptFile.js > output
```

Comment: I came here looking for `--quiet` specifically, thanks

Comment: Works with `mongosh` too

Answer (score 18):

In the new **mongodb shell 5.0+** [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/), it integrate the [Node.js fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), so you can **simply** do below in the new [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) shell:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(db.collectionName.findOne()))
```

This also avoid problems such as the `ObjectId(...)` being included in the `tojson` result, which is **not valid** JSON string.

The above code works according to the docs describes:

> The MongoDB Shell, mongosh, is a **fully functional JavaScript and Node.js 14.x REPL** environment for interacting with MongoDB deployments. You can use the MongoDB Shell to test queries and operations directly with your database.

The old *`mongo`* shell **already** marked as ***Legacy***, so use the [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) if possible.

Comment: I needed to convert the iterated response via `.toArray()`, without it there was an error "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: When tried from mongosh within compass this gives "fs is not defined"

Answer (score 15):

There are ways to do this without having to quit the CLI and pipe `mongo` output to a non-tty.

To save the output from a query with result `x` we can do the following to directly store the json output to `/tmp/x.json`:

```
> EDITOR="cat > /tmp/x.json"
> x = db.MyCollection.find(...).toArray()
> edit x
>
```

Note that the output isn't strictly Json but rather the dialect that Mongo uses.

Comment: why not just 

`EDITOR="cat > x.json"`

Comment: I didn't test if redirection worked. It seems that works just as well. Nice catch!

Comment: For Windows, replace `cat` with `type`. (`writeFile` function also works)

Comment: is there something similar for mongosh? when I do `edit x` it complains about a missing semicolon before `x`.

Comment: FYI if you use `let x` you'll get `SyntaxError: redeclaration of let x` when you use the `edit` command... still works though

Comment: @JosephSummerhays For mongosh, use `config.set('editor', '...')` instead of setting the `EDITOR` variable

Answer (score 7):

It may be useful to you to simply increase the number of results that get displayed

> In the mongo shell > `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 3000`

and then you can select all the results out of the terminal in one go and paste into a text file.

*It is what I am going to do :)*

(from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705615/1290746)

Answer (score 6):

## Combining several conditions:

- write mongo query in JS file and send it from terminal
- switch/define a database programmatically
- output all found records
- cut initial output lines
- save the output into JSON file

**myScriptFile.js**

```
// Switch current database to "mydatabase"
db = db.getSiblingDB('mydatabase');

// The mark for cutting initial output off
print("CUT_TO_HERE");

// Main output
// "toArray()" method allows to get all records
printjson( db.getCollection('jobs').find().toArray() );
```

**Sending the query from terminal**

`-z` key of `sed` allows treat output as a single multi-line string

$> `mongo localhost --quiet myScriptFile.js | sed -z 's/^.*CUT_TO_HERE\n//' > output.json`

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: you could use `mongoexport` like so:

```bash
mongoexport --uri mongodb://localhost/mydb \
  --collection "my_collection" \
  --quiet \
  --limit 1 \
  --out my_file.json
```