# How to paginate output inside mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, usability, mongodb-shell

Is it possible to pipe results in to a pager from within a mongo shell?

The mysql cli equivalent would be:

> mysql> pager less

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use mongo --eval option. Something like:

```
mongo <db> --quiet --eval '<query>' | less
```

Comment: But then you lose the autocompletion of the mongo shell

Answer (score 3):

Mongo shell already paginates the results if the returned cursor is not assigned to a variable. From the documentation:

> ...in the mongo shell, if the returned cursor is not assigned to a
>   variable using the var keyword, then the cursor is automatically
>   iterated up to 20 times to print up to the first 20 documents that
>   match the query. The mongo shell will prompt Type it to iterate
>   another 20 times.
>
> You can set the DBQuery.shellBatchSize attribute to change the number
>   of iteration from the default value 20.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. This only paginates based on the number of results, even if the content overflows the screen height, plus I have to type "it" to move to the next set of records.

eg. In mongo, searching for db.users.find().pretty() would overflow the screen height even with a DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1 -> http://i.imgur.com/VwGJYqr.png

with a mysql pager, the results get paged in relation to the screen height, regardless of a limit; so "select * from users\G" gives me -> http://i.imgur.com/fCsj6P9.png

And you can see that I can even search inside the buffered results.

Comment: @davidmh If I'm not mistaken MongoDB doesn't have what you want. You could probably do a script to do a manual format according to your wishes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem possible, but you can output to a file, and then read your file with a pager in another terminal:

```
$ mongo | tee file.txt
```

See [Printing Mongo query output to a file while in the mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565231/printing-mongo-query-output-to-a-file-while-in-the-mongo-shell).