# How to use load() function from mongo shell to load a javascript and save result to a file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Let say I have a java script file "mongo.js" where i print some data from mongoDb to the shell console.It's possible to save that output to a txt file?
The js file content:

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/test");
var cursor=db.test.find();
cursor.forEach(
   function(doc){
       print(doc.name);
   }
);
```

This is how I execute the file in mongo shell

```
load("mongo.js")
```

How to redirect the javascript output to a file?
Tried so far:

```
mongo.exe --quiet mongo.js > file.txt
mongo.js > file.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Mongo query output to a file while in the mongo shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565231/printing-mongo-query-output-to-a-file-while-in-the-mongo-shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it from terminal:

```
mongo mongo.js > "path to file"
```