# How to export profile data to a file from mongo console command line

Tags: mongodb

from the mongo console how do I export the profile data to a file

when I run this command `db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt : 20000 } } ).pretty()`

How do I get all the data into text file

Comment: Is this useful for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565231/printing-mongo-query-output-to-a-file-while-in-the-mongo-shell

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your OS. I have run the following on mac.

```
mongo --quiet --eval "db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt : 20000 } } ).pretty()" > dummy.json
```

`--quiet` will ignore all the server info which you get at the start

`--eval` will run the command for you. You can also run script as a js file. Simply remove the `--eval` and "". And replace it with `someScript.js`

Comment: This did not work I got this error in dumm.json 2020-07-30T14:04:45.205+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token : . FYI when i try to query the profile "mongo" and then "use  <my-db>". then run db.system.profile

Comment: You can also try, "db.getSiblingDB('admin').profile...". Read more details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#database-profiler